# How to search from database with multiple tables into multiple datagridviews

Tags: c#, sql-server, search, datagridview

I'm trying to implement a search function which returns multiple tables from a database into multiple datagridviews.

This is my form: [image: Form image]

I'm using each stored procedure to access each table
Each database table will correspond to one datagridview

**Stored procedure to get the Style table**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchCS_V2] @Keyword nvarchar(30)
AS
 SELECT [RID]
      ,[CustomerBrand]
      ,[CustomerStyle]
      ,[ProductName]
      ,[ProductType]
      ,[ValidityDateFrom]
      ,[ValidityDateTo]
      ,[Colorway]
      ,[Season]
      ,[Factory]
  FROM [dbo].[CostSheet_Mst]
  WHERE RID Like '%' + @Keyword + '%'
  OR CustomerStyle Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR ProductName Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR ProductType Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR ValidityDateFrom Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR ValidityDateTo Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR Colorway Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR Season Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'
  OR Factory Like + '%'+ @Keyword + '%'

GO
```

**Stored procedure to get the FOB table**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchCS_FOB_V2] @Keyword nvarchar(30)
AS
 SELECT [FobRID]
      ,[RID]
      ,[FOBType]
      ,[Amount]
      ,[Currency]
  FROM [dbo].[CostSheet_FOB]
  WHERE RID IN
  (SELECT  
       [RID]
      FROM CostSheet_Mst
      where [RID] LIKE + '%' + @Keyword + '%')
    OR [FOBType] LIKE + '%' + @Keyword + '%'
    OR [Amount] LIKE + '%' + @Keyword + '%'
    OR [Currency] LIKE + '%' + @Keyword + '%'


GO
```

**This is the function that searches from the database**

```
        private void searchFromDB() 
        {

            try
            {
                string mainconn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn1);
                SqlCommand sqlcomm1 = new SqlCommand("exec [dbo].[FetchCS_V2] '"+searchTextBox.Text+"'", sqlconn); //stored procedure for master database table
                SqlCommand sqlcomm2 = new SqlCommand("exec [dbo].[FetchCS_FOB_V2] '" + searchTextBox.Text + "'", sqlconn); //stored procedure for FOB tablew
                //sqlcomm1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da1.SelectCommand = sqlcomm1;
                da2.SelectCommand = sqlcomm2;

                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                da1.Fill(dt1);
                da2.Fill(dt2);
                dataGridViewStyleSearch.DataSource = dt1;
                dataGridViewFOBSearch.DataSource = dt2;
                sqlconn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("There's an error: {0}", ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }<br>
```

`

Currently, the search function can return rows in multiple datagridviews if the search keyword is the RID
[image]]

However, if I search a field only present in the FOB table, then it'll only return the rows in that datagridview
[image]

Also, I wonder if using one stored procedure to select fields from all tables would be better?

Then I can put that into one datatable and split it (not sure how to implement that tho)

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing ? Also , as a good practice use brackets for OR statements in SQL to get the Expected output.

Comment: I want to make it so that when I search for "USD", the style table with the corresponding RID should also be displayed into the Style Specifics datagrid as the FOB table is connected to Style Specifics table foreign key through the RID

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework / Linq ?
If no , then you will have to call parent table get the Foreign key Id and filter with the Id in the child table.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not using Linq.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to search more than one table, it makes more sense to do all of them in different stored procedures.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are some articles talking about master-detail datagrid:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4094/A-Master-Detail-DataGrid

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7941/How-to-create-a-simple-Master-Slave-DataGrid

Also, check this out.

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5309418/Filter-search-on-datagridview-in-VB-NET